# application two databases depending on urls or deploy it twice?

Tags: django, django-models

I've made an application for sport results, so it has a page where to see the results, the charts the ranking etc.

what i want to do is to deploy this app for different sports. For example football (soccer for US citizens) and basketball.

what should i do?
do i have to copy the application twice? so my django project will have two apps:

```
- football 
- basketball
```

or can i have just an application called `results` and, if the url is `mydomain.com/basketball/..` it will do queries on the basketball db or if it's football `mydomain.com/football/..` it will make queries on the football db? (is this possible?)

or should i use one db and have information about the sport directly in the db?

what's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

you can put the data in one database and use two tables with name football and basketball. if you want display football infomation,your application will connect to database and use football table, the same as football,you can connect to basketball table to dispaly it. so you should use one application ,one database with tow table.
i hope all of this can help you .

Comment: in this way the application is not reusable for every sport that exists since each sport has an own table and an own model.

Comment: you are right! what i say is not flexible,if you want use one table to  finish your application ，you can use a table named sport_t and add a column named "sport_type" ,this column can have several value, such as when it is 1 stand by football,2 is basketball, 3 is volleyball ，like this you can use 4,5,6 and son on 。